# To determine if one of the Strings from a list contains the initial part of a specified string using LINQ

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, list, string

I want to achieve the following functionality using LINQ.

Case 1:

```
listOfStrings = {"C:","D:","E:"}
myString = "C:\Files"

Output: True
```

Case 2:

```
listOfStrings = {"C:","D:","E:"}
myString = "F:\Files"

Output: False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bool b = listOfStrings.Any(myString.StartsWith);
```

or slightly more verbose (but easier to understand):

```
bool b = listOfStrings.Any(s => myString.StartsWith(s));
```

Comment: Hey Marc, how did you change your answer without having an 'edit' show up?

Comment: I think it depends on a few factors: time; votes; comments - I haven't figured out the exact rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool contains = listOfStrings.Exists(s => myString.IndexOf(s)!=-1);
```

If you know that it should be at the start of the string, then:

```
bool contains = listOfStrings.Exists(s => myString.StartsWith(s));
```

**EDIT** Marc's solution is nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Any extension method:

```
bool result = listOfStrings.Any(str => str.StartsWith(...));
```